# Magento command not working on ssh terminal

Tags: magento, magento2

I logged in to my terminal for run the magento command,after login to ssh on my command prompt and hit the command,and its not returning anything.

here is the command

```
[root@new-mt5 dev.ia****nce.com]# php bin/magento indexer:reindex
[root@new-mt5 dev.ia****nce.com]#
```

after hitting the command it not returning anything, I am using this command to my magento root dir.

how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps:

1. Try to check the env.php file . check if all the environment settings are correct. make sure your SQL server is running.
2. try to check the files permission check this docs -> [Filesystem permissions](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html)
3. Make sure you PHP version are compatible with your M2 version.
4. Try to remove cache `rm -rf var/cache var/page_cache generated/code generated/metadata`

Answer (score 0):

are you on the right directory? check if the magento binary is there. you can do this by listing bin directory (`ls bin/`)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but this can help someone else

Check your php.ini for memory limits.

You can put something like 6g for a better performance or event -1 for maximum available memory.